# extracting and inserting data from a query into a column on the same table error

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query

```
"SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(TIME(mytimestamp), '%H:%i:%s') As time FROM ". $this->table_name;"
```

that extracts the time from the column timestamp. I tried inserting it into a column called time called timestamp using the following query

```
INSERT INTO admin_tmp (time) SELECT STR_TO_DATE(TIME(mytimestamp), '%H:%i:%s')
```

but I get the error

```
 "INSERT INTO admin_tmp (time) SELECT STR_TO_DATE(TIME(mytimestamp), '%H:%i:%s')"
```

The mytimestamp does exist and the first query works so I am confused on how to insert it into another column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use update command if its on the same table

```
update your_table_name
set 
time = STR_TO_DATE(TIME(mytimestamp), '%H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: I'm getting only blank columns there

Comment: let me create a fiddle for you. give me a moment.

Comment: can you provide a sample data for mytimestamp which is stored in the table ?

Comment: check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44f9d/1, also if this does not work then provide the datatype for time and mytimestamp columns.

Comment: I made a few changes to my code and it works now, I used your technique though so thanks a lot